# convert string to float16 in python

Tags: python, string, casting

I am currently using numpy (I don't know how to make a datatype float16 in python otherwise) as this:

```
a = np.string_('1.234').astype(np.float16)
```

then:

```
type(a)
numpy.float16
```

Is ther another option? Is it better?

It would be great if you could explain what am I doing when converting the python string into numpy string!

Thank you!

Comment: why would you need a float16 to begin with? what is wrong with using `float("1.234")` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, It's in a function that will be used over a lot and I will be running low in memory. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go directly from python string to `np.float16`:

```
import numpy as np

f16 = np.float16("1.234")
print(type(f16))

f16 = np.float16(1.234)  # works as well
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.float16'>
```

Reference:  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.inexact